# Textbox only allow floating point number

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is the code in html to allow only one decimal point in a textbox:

```
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

    function isNumberKey(evt) { 
         var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.which : event.keyCode


         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46) 
             return false; 
         else { 
         var input = document.getElementById("txtChar").value;
             var len = document.getElementById("txtChar").value.length; 
             var index = document.getElementById("txtChar").value.indexOf('.'); 

             if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) { 
                 return false; 
             } 
             if (index >0 || index==0) { 
                 var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index; 
                 if (CharAfterdot > 2) { 

                     return false; 
                 } 

        }

    if (charCode == 46 && input.split('.').length >1) {
        return false;
        }


         } 
         return true; 
      } 
      </script> 


</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  name="txtChar" class="CsstxtChar" maxlength="4"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to done this in asp.net using c#.This code is not properly working in asp.net.

Comment: you can add regular expression validator in place of java script. If you do in code behind (c#) then page will be postback.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150877/allowing-input-only-for-float-number

Answer (score 0):

use this it would be helpful....

```
$('.urInputField').keyup(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var regexTest = /^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
  var ok = regexTest.test(val);
  if(ok) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the id of controls may differ from what you enter in asp.net source for example when you use parent-child controls or use master pages... , So, you can not use document.getElementById simply.

as i see your code is not just to block non-digit keys as other ones suggest duplicate solutions, but it also block backspace or arrow keys and put a limit on number of digits after decimal point such that only one digit is allowed after dot. i don't change these custom algorithm you used in your code.

this code get the source element which causes the keypress from event parameters:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function isNumberKey(event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        var src = e.srcElement || e.target;
        var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    //document.getElementById("label").value = src.id; //just for test/debug

        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
            return false;
        else 
        {
            var input = src.value;
            var len = input.length;
            var index = input.indexOf('.');

            if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) return false;

            if (index > 0 || index == 0) {
                var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
                if (CharAfterdot > 2) return false;
            }

            if (charCode == 46 && input.split('.').length > 1) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: i don't know what do you plan from `if (CharAfterdot > 2) return false` as it does not have the effect you may need from it. Can you explain what limitations do you need exactly need for input text?

Answer (score 0):

Use this  Source will work good for float numbers

function isNumber(evt) {

```
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

thanks Vamsi