# Texbox restrict characters and symbols and only allow numeric values with only one decimal point

Tags: html, asp.net

Texbox restrict entering characters and symbols and only allow numeric values with only one decimal point.maximum length 4 and one value after decimal point.For eg: .2,12.3,1444
        Here is the code in html to allow only one decimal point in a textbox:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

    function isNumberKey(evt) { 
         var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.which : event.keyCode


         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46) 
             return false; 
         else { 
         var input = document.getElementById("txtChar").value;
             var len = document.getElementById("txtChar").value.length; 
             var index = document.getElementById("txtChar").value.indexOf('.'); 

             if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) { 
                 return false; 
             } 
             if (index >0 || index==0) { 
                 var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index; 
                 if (CharAfterdot > 2) { 

                     return false; 
                 } 

        }

    if (charCode == 46 && input.split('.').length >1) {
        return false;
        }
```

I want to done this in asp.net using c#.This code is not properly working in asp.net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox only allow floating point number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978936/textbox-only-allow-floating-point-number)

Answer (score 1):

Please Check [this Link](http://jqueryexamples4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/validate-input-field-allows-only-float.html) - Validate Input Field which will allows Only Float...

```
$(function(){

    $('.float-input').keyup(function(e){
      var entered_value = $(this).val();
      var regexPattern = /^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;         
      //Allow only Number as well 0nly 2 digit after dot(.)

      if(regexPattern.test(entered_value)) {
          $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
          $('.err-msg').html('');
      } else {
          $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
          $('.err-msg').html('Enter a valid Decimal Number');
      }
    });

});
```