# onkeyup regex for validating numbers

Tags: html, regex

I have below function which is used `onkeyup` for an input field. I want to allow users to enter numbers like `1 or -1` i.e positive or negative integers(no decimals) only. The regex i have used doesn't allow negative sign in the beginning. Tried different things and also looked up other questions but couldn't come with the correct one. Is there a better way to do it? Any help is much appreciated

```
function onlynumbers ()
                    {var text1 = document.getElementById("box1");
                    var numregex = /[^0-9]/gi
                    if  (numregex.test(text1.value))
                    {
                    text1.value=text1.value.replace(numregex,"");
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the input type number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regex positive negative integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930957/javascript-regex-positive-negative-integers)

Comment: I don't want the user to enter the decimal point as well. Is that possible with input type number?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10151022/3918577

Comment: Try `.replace(/^(-)|[^0-9]+/g, '$1')`

Comment: Thanks everyone !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one that matches the hyphen only when it isn't at the start of the string:

```
var numregex = /[^0-9-]|(?!^)-/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will allow for whole numbers and negative whole numbers!
`^-?[0-9]\d*$`