# How to make input box accept only floating input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 1 common text box which is my custom component, which i am using 2 places, one is to accept integer and another is float. if my `dataType=2`, it should accept only integers which i did, but how can I make the input box which should accept only float number on keypress when `dataType=3`

> html

```
<input class="form-control"
               type="text"
               [(ngModel)]="fieldValue"
               (keypress)="checkInputType($event)" />
```

> ts

```
checkInputType(event): boolean {
    if (this.dataType === 2) {
      const charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        this.alertService.error("Can't enter any character");
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (this.dataType === 3) {
      
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151022/11029897), one way to do it is by validating the number is a float with regex.

Edit: If you want to restrict the input to only floating point numbers, you can use the [`pattern` attribute on the `input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern), which validates using regex.

Comment: I want to use this on (keypress) event, and above solution only giving the alert message, not restricting input... like i did in integer

Comment: As a float can be multiple digits but will have a decimal point, there won't be a way to check if a number is a float on every key press - ex. what if I want to represent 1.8, but have only typed the "1" in the input? Edited the answer to suggest one way to validate that the final input is a float.

Comment: I just want to make my input box which should not accept any character